# SQL query is returning most recent duplicates, but not non-duplicates

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have an MySQL table (MySQL 5.7) with the following columns: id (key), email, percentage, file_name. The table logs when students (identified by email) complete certain activities.

I need to return a list that has a row for each file_name that the student has completed. If they have completed a file_name more than once I want to return the most recent attempt, based on the auto-incrementing id. I've used a few answers on here to create the following query. The file_name string matches are to isolate particular activity types and levels:

```
SELECT id, 
       file_name, 
       percentage
FROM users t1 
WHERE email IN ('name@student.com') 
AND file_name LIKE ('%IL%') 
AND file_name LIKE ('%B2%') 
AND id = (  SELECT MAX(id) 
            FROM users t2 
            WHERE t2.file_name = t1.file_name
         )
GROUP BY file_name, percentage, id
ORDER BY id;
```

This query successfully returns the most recent instance of any duplicated filenames, but doesn't return any non-duplicates. So, if a student has completed 8 file_names once, but has repeated 1 file_name twice, this query only returns one row, the most recent duplicate. It should return the 8 single activity rows, plus the most recent duplicate.

I've got it running [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=51ce84ee8fae86e41b1391218b68836b) and it works as expected - returning the non duplicates and the most recent duplicate, so I don't understand why it's not working on the database itself.

I can successfully do this using a CTE, but I'm not in control of the database and so can't upgrade to allow CTEs.

Comment: your id condition seems to be wrong, due to this you are getting single result.

Comment: "so I don't understand why it's not working on the database itself." => Because your database has something that is different from the example in the dbfiddle ?  (Please read about [mre])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big rock problem is that the correlated subquery is getting the most recent id for a `file_name` for ***any*** `email`, not just email that matches from the outer query.  Also the `GROUP BY` on the outer query seems to be unnecessary.

Keeping with the same correlated subquery pattern, we can do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id
     , t1.email
     , t1.file_name
     , t1.percentage
  FROM users t1 
 WHERE t1.email IN ('name@student.com') 
   AND t1.file_name LIKE ('%IL%') 
   AND t1.file_name LIKE ('%B2%') 
   AND t1.id = ( -- most recent id for (email,file_name) 
                 SELECT MAX(t2.id) 
                   FROM users t2 
                  WHERE t2.email     = t1.email
                    AND t2.file_name = t1.file_name
               )
 ORDER BY t1.id
```

---

With large sets, the correlated subquery pattern can can eat our lunch, and our lunchbox, even with appropriate indexes available, because that subquery will get re-executed for every row processed by the outer query (every row that isnt earlier excluded by another predicate)

I tend to rewrite the query to avoid the correlated subquery, and measure and compare performance and compare plans (EXPLAIN PLAN output.)

We could use an inline view (a "derived table" in the MySQL parlance) to get the most recent id, and then join back to the original table to get the columns associated with that id

```
SELECT t1.id
     , t1.email
     , t1.file_name
     , t1.percentage
  -- , t2.*     
 FROM ( -- most recent id for (email,file_name)
        SELECT MAX(t2.id) AS _most_recent_id
             , t2.email
             , t2.file_name
          FROM users t2
         WHERE t2.email IN ('name@student.com')
           AND t2.file_name LIKE ('%IL%') 
           AND t3.file_name LIKE ('%B2%') 
         GROUP
            BY t2.email
             , t2.file_name
      ) t3
 JOIN users t1
   ON t1.id = t3._most_recent_id
ORDER
   BY t1.id
```

---

NOTES: We can get the inline view query (the SELECT aliased as `t3`) tested and working before we incorporate that as a derived table in the outer SELECT.

In this example, its not strictly necessary for `t3` (the inline view query) to return columns `t2.email` or `t2.file_name`.  But it does make it easier to verify the results, that we are getting the highest id for a given email and file_name.  (We can use the returned values in another simpler statement `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND file_name = ?` to get the entire set of rows we picked a max id from.

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much @spencer7593 for the detailed answer, much appreciated. I can see now why it was working for a very small set, but not on the full database.